# I don't understand the claim at Proposition 12.9 on "Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space"

Tags: proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces

I don't know doing this is let's say "legit" or obeys the rules of stack.exchange if not please let me know.

[image]

I don't understand the highlighted claim. More precisely i don't understand how it reaches that conclusion from $\delta<2$. And i also think that $\beta > R_0$ as well.

$\epsilon$ at the end of $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)_\epsilon$ means that $V\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)_\epsilon$ then $|| V ||_\infty < \epsilon$. You can just start to read from the part "Let us fix a ..." previous claims and things are not relevant to my question.(e.g. Theorem 8.8 or Proposition 12.8 etc.)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Since $\delta < 2$, the dominating term is the RHS is the term with the negative sign, so the RHS is negative for $\alpha$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, wow, it is that simple. Thank you for your answer also do you think that $\beta$ should $ > R_0$ as well? Also both inner products at RHS are finite right? (Because $C^\infty_0$ is dense in $L^p$).